# Access a file on specific location from Computer to android Device

Tags: android, connection

we are trying a access a file on Computer on a specific location through wired Connection and display contents on android device. Can someone suggest how should we approach.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android device is separated to the others, hence you can't access to anything on your Computer. Think of it, computer is computer, mobile is mobile, design for security :)

Comment: but still there has to be a way to access the computer

Comment: I guess not, unless you're a device hacker :).